# Проверка запроса: произведение ставки на кол-во отработанных часов менеджерами

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеются 3 таблицы: 
Employees(Менеджеры):

```
id    Name
1     Иванов Иван
2     Петров Петр
3     Сидоров Женя
........
```

Hours(Кол-во отработанных часов. Сортировка от ранней к поздней. Две записи в день на работника):

```
ID         date_time
1          2019-01-01 09:00:01    /начало для ID 1 1ого числа
1          2019-01-01 18:30:00    /конец для ID 1 1ого числа
1          2019-01-02 09:00:00    /начало для ID 1 2ого числа
1          2019-01-02 18:00:01    /конец для ID 1 2ого числа
2          2019-01-03 09:10:00    /начало для ID 2 3его числа
2          2019-01-03 18:00:05    /конец для ID 2 3его числа
...        ...
```

Wage(Почасовые ставки):

```
 id    Pay
 1     300
 2     200
 3     240
 .......
```

- Сидоров Женя не работал, но его тоже надо отобразить в результате. 
  Результат в таком виде

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужен взгляд специалиста.Прошу проверить мой запрос:

```html
SELECT daily.id, DATEFORMAT(date_time, '%Y-%m') AS Year_month, CEIL(SUM(delta)/60)*Pay AS Sum_of_pay 
FROM ( 
SELECT id, DATE(date_time) AS date_time, TIMEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(date_time), MAX(date_time)) AS delta 
FROM Hours 
GROUP BY id, DATE(date_time)) daily
RIGHT JOIN Employees AS e ON daily.id = e.id 
INNER JOIN Wage AS w ON e.id = w.id 
GROUP BY d.id, DATEFORMAT(date_time, '%Y-%m')
```

Comment: Запрос неверный.

Comment: Akina, где ошибка, не могли бы подсказать?

Comment: Прошу прощения. Не знал о возможности определения ответа как верный. Пометил и ответил на вопрос.

Comment: Ошибка вот тут: `GROUP BY id, date_time`. Группировать надо не по значению, а по вырезанной из него компоненты даты. Иначе каждая запись составит отдельную группу. См. предыдущий Ваш вопрос и комментарий к нему.

Comment: Спасибо! А запрос с учетом правок будет отображать сотрудников, кто в месяце не работал?

Comment: *А запрос с учетом правок* А где они, правки-то? *будет отображать сотрудников, кто в месяце не работал?* При условии, что для КАЖДОГО сотрудника в таблице ставок имеется запись - да. PS. Алиас алиасить - нельзя. `) daily AS d` == syntax error.

Comment: Внес правки в основной запрос. Не могли бы посмотреть?

Comment: Ну теперь вроде похоже на правду.

Comment: Спасибо большое!